# Track subdomain in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web app where each user gets their own subdomain that points to their profile `user.app.com`

Is there anyway to track the info to see which subdomains are getting what number of views etc. Right now every subdomain just shows up as the root `/` in analytics.

Comment: Is the page navigation and URL structure of all the subdomain apps consistent? E.g. do they all have addresses like `/about` and `/profile` etc., and do you want to report on metrics for individual subdomains as well as aggregate for all combined subdomains?

Comment: @PhilipWalton all subdomains only have a root page (their profile).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new property for each subdomain.

The unique ID for them will be [uniqueID]-1, [uniqueID]-2, and so on.
They will show up in a hierarchy under your primary domain.  And each one will track on its own.

I do this with my own site for the exact same reason.

Just make sure you have the correct tracking code for the pages you want for each identifier.

Idea 2:  Then go with my second suggestion.  Go to the Dashboards section, and create a custom report.  In that report, you can have it list only the pages (subdomains) you want to show.  I don't know of any way at all to do this automatically, if that's what you're hoping.
Alternately, you can set a parameter like ?ref=user on the pages for those users, so you can easily pick out and filter what to show.

Comment: If each subdomain is truly separate this would work, but if you want to compare metrics across subdomains, this is not a good solution.

Comment: No.  If you did it that way, you would have to keep them all the same and make a custom report in the dashboard.  For what it's worth, my solution, is more to the point of the question.  Track them each in a unique fashion.

Comment: I don't think that's the point of the question. I've asked for OP for clarification.

Comment: Well...  We're all here trying to help :)

Comment: I would have to manually create a new property for each subdomain? I have hundreds of users registering daily...

Answer (score 0):

Hi making a seperate property for each domin per user won't work if there are many users - you will run out of the GA quota for proerties. 
What you need to look at "

- Behaviour>site content>all pages"
- change the the primary from page to other>Hostname
- set the secondery dimension as Page
- Set a regex filter of "^/$" (page Page)
- and Sort by pageviews

This should give you the breakdown you want.

Comment: Actually this requires one per report, but since you seem eager on winning the (imagined) argument I will simply delete that comment.